# Why Changes Won't Take Effect in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having trouble getting the changes to appear on this Wordpress website http://www.lacervecerianyc.com I'm using the "Restaurant" Theme.

Under "Our Menu" within the categories I noticed some letters are larger than others and i found how to fix the issue by changing the font size. The problem I'm having is getting the changes to take effect. even though I made the changes in the style.css nothing is showing. Letters Looks fine on Mac/apple products but not on PC. Someone told me its a rendering issue.

[Snapshot of Font Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhaXC.png)

Comment: You are required to show a minimal example of the code that shows the problem here. Links to your web site, which can change tomorrow, helps no one in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue a couple of times. Often clearing cache helps.
Not to scratch your head or anything, try this plugin:

[W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

or 
[W3 Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)

Both are highly famous. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this has anything to do with cache. Instead, try adding more font files to your template. It's rendering issue probably

Comment: Appreciate your input as well Vladeta. Thanks